# Prevent duplicate record insert Entity Framework Webooks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, duplicates, webhooks

we currently receive many webhooks per day from a third party company.

The webhooks data contain a start date and and end date and userid. When these webhooks come in I first do a check to make sure the record does not already exist in the database. eg

```
 var CheckForDuplicateRefreshWebhook = await db.DataRefreshes.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.startdate = startdate && x.enddate == enddate && x.userid == userid);

if(CheckForDuplicateRefreshWebhook == null)
{
  //Insert Record
} else {
  //Dont Insert Record
}
```

Now the issue that i'm having is that 2 exact webhooks come in milliseconds apart. This happens rarely but is still inserting both webhooks data into the database.

What i think is that the first webhook comes in and while the checking for existing record is still executing the second exact webhook is also coming in which inturn the code that is checking if the record is in the database exists has not yet finished executing and both exact webhooks are being added.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this? I've been searching on how to wait for a task to complete before continuing but still to no success.

So overall the duplicate webhooks are coming in to quick that the first insert has not completed before the second webhook is inserted.

Based on when a webhook does comes in we also execute another set of functions which also inserts another set of records into another table and also creates duplicates in the other table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a number of synchronization features . . . so many in fact it can be difficult to know for sure which to use.  Search for Semaphore, Mutex and Critical Sections . . . each has its strength and weakness . . . read them all then decide based on your exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this scenario is to put inbound data into a queue, and have a secondary thread or process work through the queue in the order the items are placed in it.

This can have performance issues since the bottleneck is the single process handling items in the queue.